# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[C@378bf509"

Tags: java, string, char

I have two questions.

1. Why can I run on String temp = new string(numbers) but not without them?
2. How is it different from the code below?  This doesn't warn of errors

```
                int src = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numbers[i]));
                int trg = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numbers[j]));
                
                numbers[i] = (char)(trg+'0');
                numbers[j] = (char)(src+'0');
                dfs(cnt-1, i, numbers);
                numbers[i] = (char)(src+'0');
                numbers[j] = (char)(trg+'0');
```

problematic code

```
    // 4. dfs function
    public static void dfs(int cnt, int start, char[] numbers) {
        
        // 4-1. finish condition
        if(cnt==0) {
//          String temp = new String(numbers);
            int current = Integer.parseInt(numbers.toString());
            if(current>result) {
                result = current;
            }
            return;
        }

        // 4-2. change execution
        for(int i=start; i<numbers.length-1; ++i) {
            for(int j=i+1; j<numbers.length; ++j) {
                char src = numbers[i];
                char trg = numbers[j];
                
                numbers[i] = trg;   
                numbers[j] = src;
                dfs(cnt-1, i, numbers);
                numbers[i] = src;   
                numbers[j] = trg;
                
            }
        }
```

error console

```
3
123 1
2737 1
32888 2Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[C@378bf509"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:786)
    at Solution.dfs(Solution.java:35)
    at Solution.dfs(Solution.java:50)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:20)
```

Answer (score 2):

`numbers` is an array. The default toString of an array will look something like [C@378bf509. new String(char[]) will turn the char[] into a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(char%5B%5D)).